# Excel Formula to Find Equal Values in Separate Cells, then Copy an Adjacent Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with geological drilling information. I am working with information that has been given to us by another company, however, their data is not formatted how we would like it so I am tasked with formatting it in excel.

We use standards in our chemical testing, however, I need to figure out what drill hole they are associated with. The Hole ID is associated with the original sample ID

***Spreadsheet:***
[image]

What I would like to do is use a formula that Looks through the D Column to find a match from the A Column, and then copies the information from the corresponding cell in the E column

I have tried to use `VLOOKUP()` formulas, however, I am struggling to get them to work

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` is right choice. However you can also use `XLOOKUP()`, `FILTER()` or `INDEX()/MATCH()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XLOOKUP there.
For e.g., =XLOOKUP(D2, $A2:$A20, $E2:$E20)

You can modify the function based on your range and lookup value.

I hope it helps